# How do I add another developer's certificate to the iOS provisioning portal?

Tags: iphone, certificate, provisioning

I've been trying to enable another developer on my team to build an iPad app that we are creating for a client, but am having no luck getting his development certificate uploading into the provisioning portal.

I'm starting to think I'm missing something simple.  My assumption is that each developer needs to have their own certificate listed on the Certificates -> Development page.  Is that right, or are we supposed to be using only one certificate?

We tried setting him up with the certificate that's currently listed, but he gets "Error: "A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain" when trying to build.

Though I had licked this provisioning thing, but I guess not :)

Thanks for any help you all can offer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to invite the developer to your account in the apple developer site.

`Member Center > People > Invitations > Invite a Person to Your Team`

This should automatically install their developer profile and then you can sign the app with the "Team Provisioning Profile".

Also check out `Organizer > Provisioning Profiles > Automatic Device Provisioning` in Xcode 4; this simplifies installing profiles.

Comment: Hey, I can't find "People" in Member center. Has this been changed or something?

Comment: @pt2ph8 : Even I am also unable to find Invite people option in Member Center !! Can you guide me whats going wrong ?

Comment: @ Devang:After you login to the provisioning portal in home scree you will find the  "Visit the Member Center now". this will take you to the  members home which will have all the options to invite or register/renew other memberships.

Comment: @pt2ph8 may be your developer account type is individual. only organization account type can invite people.

Answer (score 11):

You can add additional developers only if you have signed up as a company.
Ref: https://developer.apple.com/support/account/

Comment: @SwapnilKale thanks for pointing, Apple has made changes to their website. I've updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

Note that only certain types of Certificates can be added to certain types of Provisioning Profiles.

For example, an "App Store Distribution" provisioning profile will only show you the option to add "iOS Distribution" certificates. All of your other certificates will not be shown in the Provisioning Profile editing interface.

I hit an issue similar to this question, when one developer held all of the Distribution certs and another held the Development certs. I thought there was an issue adding the certificates to a provisioning profile due to the multi-user scenario.

The actual issue was in matching the correct types of certificates to the given type of provisioning profile.