# iOS development teams and certificates

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, certificate

Do I need to generate a certificate for every developer on the team, or they can share a certificate? if that is true, how do I install it on each machine?

Thanks.

EDIT:
How do I install existing certificate in additional computers?

Comment: According to this post they can be shared: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805353/how-many-developers-can-use-one-iphone-developer-key But it doesn't explain where to copy the keys on each machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need one certificate.  Before getting the Developer provisioning profile, make sure to add all the UUIDs for your development devices.  Then you can share that too.

Comment: How do I install existing certificate in additional computers?

Comment: Make them a developer for your organization and have them download it.

Comment: could you be more specific please? The normal instructions to setup the development environment is to make a certificate request. I don't know how to correctly install it without that. I tried to copy it to the keychain, and then the provisioning profile to the xcode but it says that the provisioning profile doesn't have a valid certificate...

Comment: have you done this part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479237/how-do-i-add-another-developers-certificate-to-the-ios-provisioning-portal

Answer (score 0):

Each developer has to be associated to the company account in order to be able to sign software. After this they can go to the Member Center Provisioning Portal and download the provisioning profile that was given to them for each computer they plan on signing software on.

They can also request another provisioning profile from their computer by logging in with their developer account, if they're associated with the company account, but in my experience it just gives the same singing key and not create a new one for everyone.

So in short, no multiple certificates are generated for the team, only one single unique one that can be used by all.